# Setting a maximum size for a music queue

Tags: discord.js

I want to make the queue list only show 10 songs at a time, because right now the bot crashes and says that every embed field can only have 1024 characters.

I've put the most important part below, you can find the rest [here](https://hastebin.com/uvihasifom.js).

```js
exports.playQueue = (guildId, channel) => {
  if (!guilds[guildId] || !guilds[guildId].nowPlaying) {
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(9955331)
      .setDescription(":mute: Not Playing");
    channel.send(embed);
    return;
  }

  var g = guilds[guildId];
  var q = "";
  var i = 1;
  let ytBaseUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
  g.playQueue.forEach((song) => {
    let ytLink = ytBaseUrl + song.id;
    let title = song.title;
    if (title.length > 30) title = title.substring(0, 19) + "... ";
    q += "`" + i++ + "`. ";
    q += `[${title}](${ytLink}) | `;
    q += "`" + song.length + "`\n";
  });

  let currSong = g.nowPlaying.title;
  if (currSong.length > 30) currSong = currSong.substring(0, 19) + "... ";
  var cs = `[${currSong}](${ytBaseUrl+g.nowPlaying.id}) | `;
  cs += "`" + g.nowPlaying.length + "`";

  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(9955331)
    .addField(":musical_note: Now Playing", cs);
  if (g.loop) embed.setFooter(" Looping playlist");
  if (q != "") embed.addField(":notes: Play Queue", q);

  channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question is too broad and hard to understand: could you show us the relevant part of your code, your previous attempts and the desired behavior? Have a look here ;) [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I added the code

Comment: I edited the question. My grammar is not good. English is not my first language.

Comment: No worries, everybody tries their best :) Would you prefer the music queue to be limited to 10 songs, or just making the embed show the first 10 but leaving the rest in the queue for later?

Comment: I want it to show first 10 and leaving the rest of the songs later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve the problem by building a queue that goes from the first to the tenth song

```js
// I chose a for loop just because I can break out of it
// This goes on until it reaches the end of the queue or the tenth song, whichever comes first
for (let i = 0; i < g.playQueue.length && i < 9; i++) {
  let song = g.playQueue[i];
  // This is your part
  let ytLink = ytBaseUrl + song.id;
  let title = song.title;
  if (title.length > 30) title = title.substring(0, 19) + "... ";

  // Instead of directly adding the next line to q, I store it in another variable
  let newline = "";
  newline  += "`" + (i+1) + "`. ";
  newline  += `[${title}](${ytLink}) | `;
  newline  += "`" + song.length + "`\n";

  // If the sum of the two lengths doesn't exceed the 1024 chars limit, I add them together
  // If it is too long, I don't add it and exit the loop
  if (q.length + newline.length > 1024) break;
  else q += newline;
}
```

This should fix it, since `q` should not exceed 1024 characters. This is a simple but effective solution in my opinion.
Feel free to let me know if something doesn't work properly ;)

Comment: let ytLink = ytBaseUrl + song.id;

song is not defined

Comment: Oops, forgot to declare `song`

Comment: Oh that's because in your code you had `i++`, fixed it again. If that still shows the same song, please try to check how the queue (`q`) is by `console.log`gin' it.

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/iqDasf/capture.png now it's this way. I want to make it like 01, 02, 03... and continue that way.

Comment: And I added the same songs. :)

Comment: Why does js have to be so dumb? XD Fixed